# What is meant by a signal being asynchronous?

Tags: c, asynchronous, signals

Both definitions from Wikipedia:

> In computer science, asynchronous I/O, or non-blocking I/O is a form
>   of input/output processing that permits other processing to continue
>   before the transmission has finished.
>
> Signals are a limited form of inter-process communication used in
>   Unix, Unix-like, and other POSIX-compliant operating systems. A signal
>   is an asynchronous notification sent to a process or to a specific
>   thread within the same process in order to notify it of an event that
>   occurred.

I can not really understand what is meant by:

> **A signal is an asynchronous notification sent to a process**

Does this mean, just like I/O, a signal is sent to a process and the process which sends the signal does not wait for the return value of the the process receiving the signal, and keeps going?

If a signal were to be synchronous, then would the sending process wait for the return value?

Comment: "asynchronous" or "a-synchronous" means not synchronized.  As the process runs, signals to it are not strongly timed in relationship to process activity - there occur "whenever".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the statement you highlight from the Wikipedia article is too general to be helpful in figuring out what is happening "under the hood."  In regard to implementation of callbacks, for example, take a look at this part of the [Open Group specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html):

> **pointer to a function**
>
> Catch signal.
>
> On delivery of the signal, the receiving process is to execute the
>   signal-catching function at the specified address. After returning
>   from the signal-catching function, the receiving process shall resume
>   execution at the point at which it was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if "asynchronous" could be left out in

> A signal is an asynchronous notification sent to a process or to a specific thread within the same process in order to notify it of an event that occurred.

Whether the sending process continues or waits is not known to the signal recipient. Neither is it of importance to the receiver (except maybe in protocols where it is "agreed" that the sender waits or continues, possibly dictating constraints on the response time by the receiver).

Another view could be:

- An asynchronous event could mean that more of the same or different events can be received from the sender before the first event has been processed by the receiver.
- A synchronous event could mean that no events of the same type will be recieved from the sender until the previous synchronous event of the type has been processed by the receiver. (It may be though that other types of synchronous or asynchronous events can be received from the sender.)

It seems that the statement of [a]synchronousness of an event is only of relevance to what the receiver can expect from the sender, but I suspect that the Wikipedia definiton refers to the sender blocking/continuing its processing, which is not of importance to the receiver.

How would this translate to multiple senders sending the same type of synchronous event to a single receiver?

Answer (score 0):

A signal is **asynchronous** because a thread may receive a signal at **any point in execution**. This contrasts with the synchronicity of all other things in the code: one statement follow another, after a function call you expect a value, this instruction follows the one before, etc... you get the idea. A signal handler may start executing at any moment (normally interrupting the current flow execution until it finishes).

The problem is that the paragraph does not refer to the same *asynchronous* term: it refer instead to non-blocking calls that may execute "in the background", allowing the current thread to do other tasks while it *waits for the response to be received* (notice how this reception is **asynchronous** in the same way signals are).